# How to add text at bottom of checkout in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, xml, text

How to add text at bottom of checkout in magento 2 after block `.checkout-container` or `column main` or `maincontent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add your additional text block after **.checkout-container** this then you can follow below steps :

1.) Create `checkout_index_index.xml` in your module or theme.

> app/code/SK/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_block" after="checkout.root" template="SK_Module::additional_block.phtml" />
      </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

2.) Create `phtml` file in your theme or module.

> app/code/SK/Module/view/frontend/templates/additional_block.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php echo "Additional Block"; ?>
```

After adding above both files clean and flush Magento cache and check output.

**Output :**
[image]

---

Now if you want to add additional block after **column main** then you can change content of below `XML` file

> app/code/SK/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="columns">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_block" after="main" template="SK_Module::additional_block.phtml" />
      </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

After changing content clear and flush Magento cache and check output.

**Output :**
[image]

---

Now if you want to add text after **maincontent** then change content of `XML` file like..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional_block" after="main.content" template="SK_Module::additional_block.phtml" />
      </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

After changing above file clean and flush Magento cache once and check output.

**Output :**
[image]

**Hope this will help you!**